# как добавить массив в item в базу firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

как добавить массив в item в базу firebase???....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

добавляю так:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            dataModel = new DataModel();
            dataModel.setDate(now);
            dataModel.setTime(currentTime);
            dataModel.setBus_station(getCompleteAddressString(lat1, lon1));
            dataModel.setLatitude(lat2);
            dataModel.setLongitude(lon2);
            dataModel.setComments(editText1.getText().toString());

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mDatabase = database.getReference("Markers");
            mDatabase.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).setValue(dataModel);
        }
    }).start();}
```

и появляется то что видно на картинке, а когда добавляю еще раз, то все переобновляется и остается так же, а мне надо чтобы добавлялить вторые данные и т.д.

Помогите новичку плиз....

Comment: то есть вам нужно в массив маркеров добавить элемент?

Comment: мне надо в каждый элемент (который выделен на картинке) ложить много данных, а не одно которое переобновляется постоянно.....